# Can I do a multilevel analysis for my study?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, pre-post-comparison, intervention-analysis

Some details about my design can be found below:

1. There are 2 groups: Group 1 and Group 2.
2. There are *different* numbers of people in each group.
3. A pre/post (measurement) of stress is taken several times for each person. However, all people have a different number of measurement times.

My hypotheses are consequently:

- Stress decreases after the intervention (pre/post).
- Stress decreases differently depending on the group.

Comment: I might be confused on this point. You measure stress several times for the *same* measure or you measured stress as a composite with several items related to stress?

Answer (score 0):

None of what you wrote makes a multileval analysis impossible. You can have different N per group and different numbers of measures per person. Of course, something else might make it impossible, but not what you've got here.

Comment: Hmm I think the wording of the question makes this a bit unclear (hence I asked for clarification). If the same person is being measured several times at both time points, wouldn't that cluster the data at both time points?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Yes, I think so, but that would mean that I would have as many clusters as I have measurements - and then more of them within one person.

That means I have 3 levels, right?
Level 3 = Group (1/2)
,Level 2 = measurement times (how do I code this then?);
Level 1 = pre/pos (0/1)

Many thanks for the help!!!